# Unicode characters in OLE CSV import

Tags: unicode, csv, utf-8, oledb, ole

I have the following code snippet.  This is used to import CSV files that are supplied to us from multiple locations around the world.  The file format is the same, and actually quite simple, First Name, Last Name, Email and some dates as well as one or two other text columns.  The problem I have is some non-english characters, russian, german, spanish characters are not being imported correctly.  When I look at the contents of the file in the DataTable it produces, for example "ÐÐ½Ð´Ñ€ÐµÐ¹" when it should produce "Андрей" and so on.  I have looked for a very long time and cant seem to find a solutions.  If I save the file into an xls and then import it, changing my connection string of course it works fine, so it seems like the jet engine could handle unicode characters.  Any help would be appreciated.  If it matters I am using VS 2010 on windows 7 64 bit.  Thanks in advance!

```
  string filename = @"C:\Data\Test.csv";
  string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Data;Extended Properties=""text;CharacterSet=UNICODE;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited"";";
  string commString = string.Format("Select * from {0}", filename);

  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connString))
  {
    connection.Open();
    using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(commString, connection))
    {
      da.Fill(dt);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I tried your example code as written (except for changing the paths) and it worked fine.  I made a test.csv file with notepad and copied your example value into it and saved it as Unicode.  I viewed the data table in the debugger and the value looked correct.  So while this doesn't help you in the slightest, it may be encouraging to know that "it worked on at least one machine in the world".  Mine is also 64-bit win7.  I happened to have VS2005 open at the moment and ran it in there, but I doubt that would make a difference.

Answer (score 3):

Try

> characterset=65001

within your connection string for UTF-8.

```
string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Data;Extended Properties=""text;characterset=65001;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited"";";
```

Follow the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx) for other codes.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me, I was facing issue with importing UTF-8 CSV file saved from Excel being imported using OPENROWSET in SQL Server. Below is the query that correctly imported the text for the file that was saved from Excel using UTF-8 CSV option. The filename in this example is utf8csv.csv saved in C:\ folder:

select * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0', 'Text;Database=c:\;characterset=65001;HDR=yes;IMEX=0', 'Select * from [utf8csv.csv]')

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft products (my only experience is with excel) require a byte order mark (BOM) as the first 2 (for UTF-16*) or 3 (for UTF-8) bytes in the file. When you save a file from excel as "Unicode Text" you can see it embeds FF FE as the first two bytes and the rest of your data is encoded as UTF-16LE. And the notepad save options to similar:

```
Notepad Encoding     BOM        Character Encoding
-------------------  ---------  --------------------
Unicode              FF FE      UTF-16LE
Unicode Big Endian   FE FF      UTF-16BE
Utf8                 EF BB BF   UTF-8
```

So check the CSV files in a hex editor or something to see if there's a byte order mark. I suspect it will be missing and its straight into the data. Becuase the raw bytes for your UTF-8 string are being interpreted as windows-1252

```
UTF-8 String:  Андрей
Bytes:         D0 90 D0 BD D0 B4 D1 80 D0 B5 D0 B9
Windows-1252:  Ð<ERR>Ð½Ð´Ñ€ÐµÐ¹
Where <ERR> is because x90 is not a valid windows-1252 byte
```

http://sodved.awardspace.info/unicode.pl

That will leave you with two options:

- If you know what the encoding of the files is (looks like UTF-8 from your syptoms), then see if you can specify it to the file processing. Often there's some parameter or option for it
- Add the byte order to the data before processing

Comment: I am running into a problem where symbols in a CSV file are getting modified and thus eluding my regexp matches. I was so flustered I began hex editing files and indeed saw some tags you mention above. THANK YOU - this is an awesome post and enlightens me on my potential problem. Now to figure out if I can get powershell's import-csv function to expect a specific encoding!

Comment: No worries. Unfortunately the hard way seems to be the only way to learn this stuff - certainly was (and still is) for me