# Openrowset problems with Umlauts/Codepage when flatfile is ANSI and not UTF8

Tags: sql-server, utf-8, ansi, sql-server-2019, flat-file

I've got a Problem with umlauts (Example: Emp**ä**nger) when using OPENROWSET. In our old envirionment with Windows Server 2012, SQL-Server 2012 and a COLLATION without UTF-8 (Latin1_General_CI_AS) everything runs without Problems. In most Times our Flatfiles are in ANSI (I think cp1252).
Now we changed to Windows Server 2016, SQL-Server 2019 and the UTF-8 Collation (Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8) and got a problem with the german Umlauts (Umlaute like **Ü**bung).

We have many Users that uses the ability to upload files and using them as an extended Version in SSRS. So it would be nice if it is just an option to change.

Our original script works fine with UTF-8 but it returns the wrong characters in ANSI:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('MSDASQL','Driver={Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)}','select * from \\localhost\_RepUploader\FlatFileTest_ANSI.csv')
```

This is what I get: "Emfpfänger" >> "Empf�nger"
When I change the Encoding from ANSI tu UTF-8 I get the correct spelling.

Here is the Content of that File:

```
FirstWord;SecondWord
Empfänger;Üben
```

In the "Schema.ini" I tried differnet CharakterSet Options: "1252,65001,OEM,ANSI,1250" and also others between the known Codepages. Without luck.

I got it Working With a Polybase External_Table Connection. I also got it working with a BULK INSERT and the Codepage 1252.

```
drop table if exists #tmp
create table #tmp (FirstWord varchar(100), SecondWord nvarchar(100))
bulk insert #tmp
from '\\localhost\_RepUploader\FlatFileTest_ANSI.csv'
with
(
    fieldterminator = ';',
    codepage = 1252,
    FIRSTROW = 2    
)
select 'ANSI File', * from #tmp
```

It seems to me, that the Polybase Connection uses the Schema.ini, because when I try CharacterSet=65001 I get the wrong Character. When I uncomment or use CharacterSet=1252, everything is fine. So how can Polybase  select the correct characters.

Comment: That's Latin1, not ANSI. Either make sure the file is UTF8 or specify the actual codepage. The best option is to use UTF8 because it eliminates guessing

Comment: `BULK INSERT` isn't Polybase at all. It's a plain old BULK INSERT command, available since the 1990s. It seems the real problem is trying to use the Access driver to read from CSVs as if they were tables. The Access driver was never meant for this. And since you never specified the codepage in the Access driver, the data was loaded using the wrong codepage long before it reached SQL Server

Comment: What are you trying to do in the first place?

Comment: I did not post the script for my Polybase testing. It was a simple create data source and create external table. so i really tried it with polybase. But, when I change the CharSet in the Schema.ini for this File I got the same false characters. How can i set the right Codepage in the Access Driver.

Comment: I have arround 50+ Users. The Users are having Lists from different sources. In most times I have no ability to change the List, because they are from external applications. Sometimes the Lists have to be extended to help the colleague do their job. so they upload the list to the reporting services server and open their reports.

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do? I can't stress enough that this driver was never, ever meant for this. It's meant for single user desktop applications, and even there, the need to match bitness (32/64-bit) with the Office installation and the application is a major pain.

Comment: What you posted isn't an attempt to upload a CSV, it's an attempt to treat a CSV as if it was a table. `BULK INSERT` is the "upload" or rather, import. `because they are from external applications` that's where the data for all ETL processes comes from. You can use either BULK INSERT or SQL Server Integration Services to load data into the reporting database

Comment: You may be able to use `characterset=1252;` in the Access connection string as [this related question shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300716/unicode-characters-in-ole-csv-import). You're using the same OLEDB provider used by SSIS and the Improt/Export Wizard which means you can use these to test the connection. Or even load the data directly

Comment: It's a grown process. I agree, that using BULK would have been the better way. I think I will change it to BULK, but there are 100+ changes to make und a handful of powerusers to inform. I would like to do the server move first and change our approach a little later. We have more than 2000 Reports to handle, so it is work enough. But if there is no other way, then it is ok. So you say BULK INSERT would be your Choice for our Problem?

Comment: I have succes using this `SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0', 'Text;Database=\\localhost\_RepUploader\', 'Select * from [FlatFileTest_ANSI.csv]')`. It makes no difference if i use characterset in the connectionstring. Strangly it works even with 65001 or 1252. I will give it a try and post my progress. At this Time Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our temporary Solution is to stay with our old script

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('MSDASQL','Driver={Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)}','select * from \\localhost\_RepUploader\FlatFileTest_ANSI.csv')
```

Our users upload files under use of an c# uploadtool. This Tool now converts all cp1252 File to cp65001 (without BOM).
Now we don't need any CharakterSet Setting in the Schema.INI.

With this converted UTF-8 File we can use our old Syntax to complete the Server switching without too many changes.

The Solution from Panagiotis also works without this convert step, but we decided to do this way, because UTF-8 is the better encoding for us.
Any CharakterSet Setting in the OPENROWSET seems to be ignored!

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0', 'Text;Database=\\localhost\_RepUploader\', 'Select * from [FlatFileTest_ANSI.csv]')
```

In the future we would focus BULK Insert. But in my tests i've had many Problems with no results und much more important no error even if there where data. Because the files we get "have passed through many hands" they are not 100% save designed. So it's better to get an error than not getting any data.